# console.memory equivalent in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I've written some nice debugging tools using console.memory in Chrome, i.e.

```
console.memory.totalJSHeapSize
```

Is there any equivalent in FireFox to gain access to the JVM heap levels at runtime in Javascript?

Comment: JVM? Should this be tagged as a Java question too?

Comment: No, it's a javascript specific question

Comment: OK then. It's just that the J in JVM is (usually) for Java...

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Memory_Profiler#Memory_profiling) what you're looking for? I'm pretty sure you will have to leverage firebug to get anything like Chrome's console.

EDIT: It looks like firebug's API might help you out: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API